# Can we Run Two Jenkins on same windows machine

Tags: jenkins

I was trying to install two Jenkins on same windows box and am having tough time doing it.some blogs say it is easy and some advice not to do it.. if someone has done it . can that person send me step by step guide to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how you run your Jenkins instances, if you use java -jar jenkins.war, then it's no problem as long as you make sure that you specify different `JENKINS_HOME` and http port.

So, for example:

```
java -DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins1 -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080
java -DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins2 -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
```

This will start two Jenkins instances, one on port 8080 and one on 8081.

If you're using a container to run Jenkins, look [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Containers) for information on how to set `JENKINS_HOME` and `--httpPort`.